# comparison of randomized algorithms

Tags: algorithm, random

Sometimes randomized algorithms return quite good results and they are often much faster than a deterministic alternatives. But how can I compare two randomized algorithms (or at least their implementations) ? The results will differ after each call and the output will highly depend on a (pseudo)-coincidence.

I have to compare some clustering algorithms and the majority of solutions is randomized.

- is it smart to compare the distribution of the output? (This will highly depend on input and the coincidence.)
- it is also quit hard to estimate the duration because some algorithms work until a threshold is reached (= depends highly on input).

Comment: First define your criteria: when would one algorithm perform better than another? Then use statistical methods to do the comparison.

Comment: compare what? precision? recall? complexity? estimated practical speed?